# Can a proxy enable a client to talk to an https server with an unsupported ssl cipher?

Tags: ssl, proxy

I'm using a certain piece of software whose development has been stopped, which particularly means its SSL ciphers are not being upgraded anymore. This means it becomes more and more unable to communicate with https servers as they upgrade the minimum required ssl ciphers.

Is there a simple pass-through web proxy that can be configured to step inbetween such requests and upgrade the SSL cipher on the request without the software needing to support it?

Answer (score 2):

With simple pass through this is not possible, since this would also pass through the SSL handshake unchanged and thus the ciphers offered by the client. You would need a proxy doing SSL interception to create a (weak) SSL connection between client and proxy and then another (strong) SSL connection between proxy and server. Such proxy software exist, for example [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/).

Comment: I looked at http://docs.mitmproxy.org/en/stable/index.html and could not spot what feature would do the ssl upgrading. Could you point that out?

Comment: @Mithaldu: The central feature of mitmproxy is to do a man in the middle of the connection. And this is exactly what is needed here: "... SSL-capable man-in-the-middle proxy"

Comment: If i just run mitmproxy and use it as an https proxy, i only get errors like this: Error connecting to "www.soldierfromthesurface.com": [Errno 1] _ssl.c:498: error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error

Comment: @Mithaldu: I have no idea which version of mitmproxy and which version of python you are using but I would recommend to use the latest of both. The error you report looks related to Server Name Indication, see also https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues/745